# How to use one reducer to update any state column

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to keep things "DRY" in my react functional application. Here I have two states:

1. finance.js
2. customer.js

In finance.js, I have a customer:

```js
  import { initialState as customerState } from './customer.js'

  export const initialState = {
    [...]
    customer: { ...customerState },
    [...]
  }

  export const reducer = (state, action) => {...}
```

Inside customer.js file, I want to have its own reducer

```js
  // customer state file

  export const initialState = {...}

  export const reducer = (state, action) => {...}
```

Back in finance.js, I wish not having to define another reducer action to set the customer information. I want to reuse the customer's reducer function, inside customer, so it updates the finance's state (customer). Is this possible? This is where I am lost:

```js
  import { useReducer } from 'react'
  import { 
    initialState, 
    reducer 
  } from './finance.js'

 import {  
    reducer as customerReducer
  } from './customer.js'

  export default function Foo() {

    // [...]
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)

    // I need to use customerReducer (dispatch) to update finance's state. How?

    return //...
  }
```

To update the customer object in the finance state, I'd normally create a reducer action, for customer, inside of `finance.js`, I don't want that because if I now need to use the customer state elsewhere, I'd have to create the same reducer action inside `customer.js`.

I have not tried anything and the only thing comes to mind is using "Context" but I do not see how that would work here.

Or, if I update the customer state then the customer information inside `finance.js` should also be updated. Possible, in a clean manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My general advice would be to avoid mixing reducers as much as possible.

I would put that principle even before keeping DRY code because it increases the complexity of your code and removes a big benefit of the Flux pattern: having small pieces of testable code with a defined scope.

However, if you need your finance reducer to call some code on your customer reducer - I would dispatch a "create customer" action from your finance reducer.

You can also use tools liks Redux Saga or Redux Thunk to handle this as a side effect - Saga for example can dispatch your customer action everytime your finance action is dispatched.

Comment: Thanks. So what you are saying is to use Redux as useReducer is not what I'm after? I feel useReducer maybe a bit "basic" in this case.

Comment: To get your system to be explicit, I would focus on dispatching two actions. So the question is how do you trigger your customerAction after your financeAction is over. Redux-Saga or Redux-Thunk are a way to solve that problem